# seo friendly urls not recognised by IIS

Tags: iis, seo

I have a php based site hosted on a IIS server. URL like http://host.net/t.php works but
without the php extension does not work. This site was working properly on a LINUX server previously. ISAPI rewrite Life version was installed on the IIS server. But the problem still persists.

Answer (score 0):

IIS versions prior to 7.x doesn't support extension-less URLs without some ISAPI filter.

This is the reason ;)

**EDIT:
Read this blog post:
http://thebackshop.posterous.com/extensionless-urls-with-sitecore-using-the-he
Was it useful for you? Good luck! :)**

Comment: You'll need to find one supporting extension-less URLs. Let me find one.

Comment: Check my answer, I've updated it with some EDIT! Let me know if this is enough for solving your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by installing IIRF Rewrite 3 module.

Comment: Please either accept your own answer or delete the question - This prevents others coming here trying to solve a problem you've already fixed. Thanks